# Backup Exec 2012 - Global exclusions by directory name?

Tags: backup, backupexec, symantec

I'm kind of a n00b with BE, so forgive me if this should be obvious.

With other backup systems in the past, we have had a general policy of excluding any folder named DoNotBackup. This provides a convenient means of omitting large and/or temporary files.

I was hoping to exclude these folders from my BE backups by setting a global exlusion, thus:

```
Resource name: \\*\*
Path: **\DoNotBackup
Name: *.*
Apply to subdirectories: yes
```

However, this appears not to work. At first, I thought we had something wrong with the resource/path syntax, but then I spotted this in the documentation:

> You can configure Backup Exec to exclude certain files, or certain
>   types of files, from backups. Exclusions can be added to incremental
>   and differential backup jobs, but not full backup jobs.

Is it really true that I can't tell BE to globally exclude by name in full backups? Of course I could explicitly unselect these folders in the individual jobs, but the idea is to be able to create these folders on an *ad hoc* basis. Perhaps there's some other mechanism for doing this that's not obvious to someone without a lot of experience? (tbh, I find the BE interface almost—but not quite—as frustrating as Symantec's phone support.)

BE 2012 (Version 14.0)